# Earned Custodian badge reviewing suggested edit without having privilege to review it

Tags: support, badges, review

I have just 135 reputation on [Pro Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com) and I have earned the Custodian badge for reviewing Suggested Edits. Is it a bug because reviewing suggested edits it requires 2k reputation, and I only have 135?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not a bug. It is by design. You can earn this badge by reviewing suggested edit on your own post too. And you have earned this badge by reviewing [this suggested edit on your own post](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/9059).

Comment: ohk thanks for your answer now I understood